# Android Build Errors Google Play Services

Tags: android

I am compiling an Android project and getting the following errors:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services:+.
     Required by:
         MyApp:app:unspecified
```

I am using Android Studio.

**UPDATE:**

The AndroidManifest.xml file has these two settings:

```
 <!-- Target -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

In my Android Studio Module Settings I have the following:

[image]

I have also installed the Google Repository and Play Services.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add Android Support Repository to Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958213/how-to-add-android-support-repository-to-android-studio)

Comment: I have already installed Google Support Library and Google Play Library but I still get the same error.

Comment: Might be a stupid question but do you have both the latest versions of play services and google repository ?

Comment: I  have updated the question with more details.

Comment: It doesn't use the setting you have in the screenshot of your Project SDK; it uses the SDK that's in your local.properties file. Make sure that the SDK pointed to by that file has the Google Repository installed; perhaps you have more than one SDK and the one it's actually using doesn't have the repository.