# Android Studio Espresso Testing Error: Empty Test Suite

Tags: android, testing, junit, android-espresso

I keep running into the following error when trying to execute my tests in Android Studio: Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}

My test class is in the androidTest/java directory and has a constructor. My build.gradle is correct too. Any help is appreciated.

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class AndroidUITests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<UserActivity>{

    private UserActivity userActivity;

    public AndroidUITests() {
        super(UserActivity.class);
    }


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        userActivity = getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPhoneIconIsDisplayed() {
        // When the phone_icon view is available,
        // check that it is displayed.
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.groupCreate)).perform(click())
                .check(matches(withText("Enter a name")));
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
}
```

Comment: When in doubt, refer to the official examples: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to update the test "Edit Configuration" and include the AndroidJUnitRunner as the instrumentation runner.

[image]

I found the solution in this video:
https://youtu.be/TGU0B4qRlHY?t=9m36s

**Updated**

Adding what @loeschg suggest:
Make sure you check the logcat logs to ensure something isn't causing issues (crash) before the test is even run. Bad code in the @BeforeClass block could resulted in the "Empty Test Suite" message in Android Studio despite having properly set the test runner.

Comment: Runner can no longer be specified in Run/Debug Configurations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Updated hint! Saved my time!

Answer (score 27):

*While the question is already answered, figured it was worth posting for future visitors.*

Make sure you **check the logcat logs** to ensure something isn't causing issues (crash) before the test is even run. I had bad code in my `@BeforeClass` block which resulted in the "Empty Test Suite" message in Android Studio despite having properly set the test runner.

Comment: also make sure you set the correct run configuration - if you use "All in package" option, it can mismatch the applicationId if you use `applicationIdSuffix` option

Comment: Thanks this was the case, I wish if the error was not misleading :)

Answer (score 7):

If you get such error message:

```
Class not found: "com.example.product.package.name.SomeSpecificTest" Empty test suite.
```

You need to make sure if your Espresso test is added under `Android Instrumented Tests` section in `Run/Debug Configurations`.

It seems like **Android Studio 3.1.3** is sometimes adding it incorrectly to `Android JUnit` section instead.

Make sure it looks something like this:
[image: Run/Debug Configurations with Android Instrumented Tests and Android JUnit]

Also, worth mentioning that I've noticed, that this issue occurs for me while a non `Debug` build variant is selected.

Comment: I noticed this happening to me too. Deleted the test from Android JUnit section and cleaning the project did work for me from next test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` is provided by the runner library.

1. Install the [Android Support Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20200794/44816) (which you've already done)
2. Add runner to your dependencies

it should look like this

```
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still bother with this in 2018, here is working setup:

`build.gradle` (**required**):

```groovy
<...snip...>

android {
    defaultConfig {
        <...snip...>
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // ^^^ here it is (first)!
    }

<...snip...>

dependencies {
    <...snip...>

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    // ^^^ all three required ^^^ (second)
}
```

And in instrumented tests (**required** too):

```kotlin
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onData
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.*
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.*
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.RootMatchers.*
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class ApplicationTest {
    @Test
    fun thruStillThrullyThrue() {
        // do interaction with some UI
        onView(withId(R.id.myButtonOnMyActivity)).perform(click())

        // assert expected result
        onView(withId(R.id.myTextViewOnMyActivity)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}

// (third)
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the field 'testInstrumentationRunner' is specified in the build.gradle (app). Change that to the androidx if you are using it (androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner)

Hope it helps someone, cheers!