# java.lang.Exception: Custom runner class AndroidJUnit4 should have a public constructor with signature AndroidJUnit4(Class testClass)

Tags: android, android-espresso

gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.developer.taskmaker"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.2.0'
    debugCompile 'im.dino:dbinspector:3.4.1@aar'
    // Android JUnit Runner
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    // Android runner and rules support

    // add this for intent mocking support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'

    // add this for webview testing support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

Unit test case looks like

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void buttonClick(){
        onView(withId(R.id.fab)).perform(click()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

}
```

Error message looks like:

```
java.lang.Exception: Custom runner class AndroidJUnit4 should have a public constructor with signature AndroidJUnit4(Class testClass)

    at org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError.<init>(InitializationError.java:38)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:111)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.collectWrappedRunners(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.getClassesRequest(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:51)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:91)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:95)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

I have already check other answers but not getting solution.Please tell where thing goes wrong. When running this code I am getting error

Comment: Can you show the imports for your "unit test case"?

Comment: Also, those testing support dependencies should be in `androidTestCompile`, not `compile`. What happens if you change them to `androidTestCompile`?

Answer (score 36):

## Cause 1: placing tests in the wrong folder

This error can be replicated by making a new Application with the default template in Android Studio and copying the auto-generated `ExampleInstrumentedTest` from the `androidTest` folder to the `test` folder:

[image: incorrectly copying an instrumented test into the test folder]

Here's what the error looks like:

[image: the OPs error java.lang.Exception: Custom runner class AndroidJUnit4 should have a public constructor with signature AndroidJUnit4(Class testClass)]

Note that in order to replicate the problem you would also have to incorrectly add dependencies to the module-level `build.gradle`:

[image: dependencies in the wrong place]

## Cause 2: wrong test configuration

Local unit tests and instrumented tests have different Run configurations. If you click *Edit Configurations* like below:

[image: test configuration]

You should see your instrumented tests under `Android Instrumented Tests` and your local unit tests under the `Android JUnit` like in the illustrations below:

For Android Instrumented Tests the config should look something like below:

[image: test config for Android Instrumented tests]

For Android JUnit:

[image: test config for Android JUnit tests]

When you run a test, Android Studio will create a run config for you. If the run config is in the wrong category, check you have your `test` and `androidTest` folders correct and then you can delete the run config from the `Edit configurations` and run the test again. If you have set up correctly, Android Studio will use the correct type of run configuration this time.

## Explanation

There are two types of tests in Android:

1. Instrumented tests
2. Local unit tests

## Instrumented tests

**Instrumented tests** are tests that are designed to run on a **handset** or **emulator**. These are tests where you need access to a fully-functional part of the Android library (like a real `Context` for example). These need to go in the `androidTest` folder and dependencies for these tests (e.g., Espresso, `com.android.support.test.rules:0.5`) will be prefixed with `androidTestCompile` in your `build.gradle`.

Here is an example instrumented test:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

/**
 * Instrumentation test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        assertEquals("com.gyaltsab.myapplication", appContext.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

## Local unit tests

**Local unit tests** are tests that you can run **in your IDE**. They normally don't depend on any part of the Android library not available on a standard JVM (e.g., they won't depend on `Context`). The dependencies for these go in the `testCompile` part of your `build.gradle`.

Here is an example unit test:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * Example local unit test, which will execute on the development machine (host).
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }
}
```

Note that local unit tests do not need the `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` annotation in the class declaration. Please see [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: After double-checking both of your causes, I am still getting this error...

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I'm working in Android studio 2.3.1. I checked my run configurations. Under Run->Edit Configurations and discovered the test I was trying to run as an instrumented test was under the Android JUnit tests category, even though I had it in the androidTest directory in my project. I added an Android Instrumented Test (hit the plus button in the corner) and set it to point to the test I was trying to run. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your test file to the androidTest folder.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was solved by putting the below line:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

solution:- you have to change the test folder from test to androidTest and edit the test configuration.(or move the test file from test to androidTest edit the test configuration)

I found the solution in this video: https://youtu.be/TGU0B4qRlHY?t=9m36s

and here:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30172064/5723125