# AndroidJUnit4 Should have a public constructor

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I'm trying to follow Android Developer Docs to write an Instrumented Unit Test, but, of course, it doesn't work. I am getting the error:

```
Custom runner class AndroidJUnit4 should have a public constructor with signature AndroidJUnit4(Class testClass)
```

when ever I run my example test:

```
package com.devetry.ytp

import android.content.Context
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Rule

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleAndroidTest {

    /**
     * VARIABLES
     */



    /**
     * LIFE CYCLE
     */


    /**
     * Example Android Test
     *
     * An example android test
     */
    @Test
    fun exampleAndroidTest() {
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
        Assert.assertEquals("com.devetry.ytp", context.packageName)
    }

}
```

I have tried tried multiple solutions to this specific error I found online, but like most things Android, the solution was either outdated or just simply didn't work. Unfortunately, of all of the solutions, I was unable to even recognize a common theme, thus leaving me stranded.

How can I resolve the error and just get an Instrumented Unit Tests to run?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478370/4936904

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh yup, tried both of those. My Instrumented Test is in the AndroidTest folder and my configuration looks exactly the same...

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.devetry.ytp

import android.content.Context
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

// AndroidJunitRunner and AndroidJUnit4 are not from the same pacakge
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Rule

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleAndroidTest {

    /**
     * VARIABLES
     */



    /**
     * LIFE CYCLE
     */
...
}
```

You are not using the classes from the same package, make sure they are consistent. The support test package is conflict with androidx package.

Comment: Please consider copying, pasting and properly formatting any code that you include in your example, rather than use images of character data.