# android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-library, android-sdk-tools

EDIT: I have looked at a ton of related posts and couldn't find any to help because they all suggest to add the same library that I cannot find in my sdk because it looks different than what I am seeing in the posts

I have spent hours trying to figure this out and I can't get it. I downloaded the support library and repository from the Android SDK and when I try to import the support library, I don't have the path

```
<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/
```

that it tells me to navigate to. The path I am seeing is:

```
sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/
```

I do not know where the library is that I need to add because every post/instructions points me to a directory that I don't see.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25365406/1715829

Comment: @Buddy Yes just finished reading that before this post. I have both the android library and android repository installed, but I still don't see the path that I should be seeing

Comment: i think here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890530/actionbaractivity-is-deprecated-android-studio

Comment: @YenMinh I've seen this and it hasn't fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

hi Brejuro you sdk path must be hidden firstly show hidden folder then check
url given below:

`C:\Users\your_compuer_name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`