# Is the Maven repository holding the same Android dependencies as the Gradle one?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm doing an Android app that needs the latest support library.

If I understand correctly the latest version is 22.2.0

So I'm trying to get the com.android.support - appcompat-v7 version 22.2.0 dependency but it is not found on search.maven.org

As one can see, it is the one required by the gradle dependency on this article:

```
http://androidgifts.com/navigation-view-using-design-support-library/#comment-11
```

The latest android sdk android-sdk_r24.3.3-linux.tar does not have it. It only has the 22.2.0 version.

How come Maven does not have it ?

Any way to download it ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here > [Android support library setup with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380337/android-support-library-setup-with-maven) google actually don't care much for maven users...
One of the answers mentioned there might help you (probably not as easy as you'd like, but...): https://stackoverflow.com/a/22602712/4405559

I'd also advise you to try finding a github repo containing the newest appcompat (the question I've linked has also got an answer mentioning how you can create your own repo, if needed).

Comment: You would know where to find the 22.2.0 version ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just followed the steps in this stackoverflow answer in my maven project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22602712/4405559 and it works perfectly.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
        <version>22.2.0</version>
        <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```

The gradle dependency would be:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0@aar'
```

(If it doesn't find it you may need to add the local android support m2repository folder to your repositories. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365406/2199475)

Just make sure you have run check for updates in the Android SDK Manager and install the correct api and associated SDK Build-tools.